# Sphinxsearch upgrade, partial search is not working

Tags: upgrade, search

I upgraded SS from Sphinx 2.0.4 to Sphinx 2.2.11, some attributes commented in config.

Searching is working now, but not for partial search, on old version partial search worked. For example `compu` found all match cases, so `computer` too.

But now, on new version, searching is working only for 100% match, so `comp` found 0
results, you must write all word, `computer`.

Where is the catch?

Thanks.

Here is part of config file.

```
    listen = 127.0.0.1:3312

    log                 = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log

    query_log           = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log

    read_timeout        = 5

    max_children        = 30

client_timeout = 300
persistent_connections_limit    = 30

    pid_file            = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid


    seamless_rotate     = 1

    preopen_indexes     = 1

    unlink_old          = 1
mva_updates_pool    = 1M
max_packet_size     = 8M
max_filters     = 256
max_filter_values   = 4096
max_batch_queries   = 32

}
```

Comment: OK, why `-1`? It is ubuntu service related, so WHY? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just info, problem was in language/chars/diacritics. I added this option.

```
 charset_table      = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, /, -, a..z, U+26, U+0e1->a, U+0c1->a, U+10d->c, U+10c->c, U+10f->d, U+10e->d, U+0e9->e, U+0c9->e, U+11b->e, U+11a->e, U+0ed->i, U+0cd->i, U+148->n, U+147->n, U+0f3->o, U+0d3->o, U+159->r, U+158->r, U+161->s, U+160->s, U+165->t, U+164->t, U+0fa->u, U+0da->u, U+16f->u, U+16e->u, U+0fd->y, U+0dd->y, U+17e->z, U+17d->z, U+0e4->a, U+0c4->a, U+139->l, U+13a->l, U+13d->l, U+13e->l, U+154->r, U+155->r, U+0fc->u, U+0dc->u, U+170->u, U+171->u, U+0f6->o, U+0d6->o, U+0f4->o, U+0d4->o, U+150->o, U+151->o
```